# Pyautogui in specific screen app in 2 monitors

Tags: python, pyautogui

Well, let's separate this doubt into parts.
First question, how can I make pyautogui.locateOnScreen() in a specific app window on windows? Example, search for an image only in the windows calculator?

The second question is I have 2 monitors, how do I search for an image on a specific monitor?

I make a simple code, but not working because my calculator is opened on my second monitor.

```
def main():
    try:
        while True:
           button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/calc7Key.png', region=(0,0,1920, 1080), confidence=.5)
           print(button7location)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone.')

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer may be late but for those looking, the answer is here :
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/321

**quote** - Resolve for me

> If still relevant for someone on windows:
>
> In my opinion the issue is, that the current version of pyscreeze
> utilizing >ImageGrab (Pillow) on windows only uses single-screen grab.
>
> ---
>
> *A dirty quick fix in **pyscreeze** could be:*
>
> ---
>
> - enable all_screen grabbing:
>
> In file: ***`pyscreeze/__init__.py`***, function: `def _screenshot_win32(imageFilename=None, region=None):`
>
> change `im = ImageGrab.grab()` to `im = ImageGrab.grab(all_screens= True)`
>
> ---
>
> - handle new introduced negative coordinates due to multiple monitor:
>
> In file: ***`pyscreeze/__init__.py`***, function: `def locateOnScreen(image, minSearchTime=0, **kwargs):` behind `retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)` >add
>
> ---
>
> ```
> if retVal and sys.platform == 'win32':
>     # get the lowest x and y coordinate of the monitor setup
>     monitors = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()
>     x_min = min([mon[2][0] for mon in monitors])
>     y_min = min([mon[2][1] for mon in monitors])
>     # add negative offset due to multi monitor
>     retVal = Box(left=retVal[0] + x_min, top=retVal[1] + y_min, width=retVal[2],height=retVal[3])
> ```
>
> ---
>
> - don't forget to add the `import win32api`
>
> In file: ***`pyscreeze/__init__.py`***:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> if sys.platform == 'win32': # TODO - Pillow now supports ImageGrab on macOS.
>     import win32api # used for multi-monitor fix
>     from PIL import ImageGrab
> ```

Comment: In WIndows this is working perfectly in 2024

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately pyautogui currently doesn't work with multiple monitors, you can find it in their [FAQ](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Q: Does PyAutoGUI work on multi-monitor setups.

> A: No, right now PyAutoGUI only handles the primary monitor.

As of searching specific area you can use optional `region=(startXValue,startYValue,width,height)` parameter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527880/12444149).

Comment: Ok, and my second question? how using in specific app screen?