How do send keys and mouse clicks to an inactive window on the second monitor?
I have a code where I use OpenCV to look for matches for certain pictures and click on them. In a full-screen app on the main monitor. I want to improve my code so that I can use applications on a third monitor and at the same time send keystrokes and mouse that would not interfere with this.
import time
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import keyboard

#from window_cap import WindowCapture
class FindGem:
    def __init__(self, main_agent, print_menu):
        self.main_agent = main_agent
        self.march_target = cv.imread('IMG/gem_pit.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.march_target = np.array(self.march_target)
        self.march_target1 = cv.imread('IMG/gem.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.march_target1 = np.array(self.march_target1)
        self.march_thead = cv.imread('IMG/pic1.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.march_thead = np.array(self.march_thead)
        self.march_thead1 = cv.imread('IMG/pic3.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.march_thead1 = np.array(self.march_thead)
        self.gather = cv.imread('IMG/gather1.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.gather = np.array(self.gather)
        self.troop = cv.imread('IMG/new_troop1.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.troop = np.array(self.troop)
        self.march = cv.imread('IMG/march.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.march = np.array(self.march)
        self.time = cv.imread('IMG/time.png',cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.time = np.array(self.time)
        self.findplace = cv.imread('IMG/find.png', cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        self.findplace = np.array(self.findplace)
        self.running = True
        self.paused = False
        self.q_pressed = False
        self.print_menu = print_menu
        self.movement_sequence = ['right'] * 13 + ['down'] + ['left'] * 13 + ['down']
        self.current_movement_index = 0
        self.move_camera_count = 0
        #self.wincap = WindowCapture('Rise of Kingdoms')

    def start_place(self):
        screen = self.main_agent.screen1
        march_location = cv.matchTemplate(screen,
                                          self.findplace,
                                          cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        march_loc_arr = np.array(march_location)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(march_loc_arr)
        threshold = 0.7
        if max_val >= threshold:
            x, y = max_loc
            x += 14
            y += 12
            screen_pos2 = x, y
            pyautogui.moveTo(screen_pos2[0], screen_pos2[1], 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            #X coordinate
            pyautogui.write('868')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            # y coordinate
            pyautogui.write('1181')
            pyautogui.moveTo(1194, 292, 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.find_gem()
        else:
            print('Not Found')


    def find_gem(self):
        if self.main_agent.screen1 is not None:
            screen = self.main_agent.screen1
            march_location = cv.matchTemplate(screen, self.march_target, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            march_loc_arr = np.array(march_location)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(march_loc_arr)
            x, y = max_loc
            threshold = 0.52
            if max_val >= threshold:
                print('Found')
                if self.march_thead is not None:
                    square_size = 150
                    x += 66
                    y += 36
                    top_left = (max(0, x - square_size // 2), max(0, y - square_size // 2))
                    bottom_right = (min(screen.shape[1], x + square_size // 2), min(screen.shape[0], y + square_size // 2))
                    square_region = screen[top_left[1]:bottom_right[1], top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]]
                    #cv.imshow("Square Region", square_region)
                    #cv.waitKey(0)
                    second_march_location1 = cv.matchTemplate(square_region, self.march_thead, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                    second_march_location2 = cv.matchTemplate(square_region, self.march_thead1, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                    second_max_val1 = cv.minMaxLoc(second_march_location1)[1]
                    second_max_val2 = cv.minMaxLoc(second_march_location2)[1]
                    threshold = 0.5
                    if second_max_val1 >= threshold or second_max_val2 >= threshold:
                        print('Found second type')
                        self.move_camera()
                    else:
                        print('No second type found, processing first type')
                        x, y = max_loc
                        x += 66
                        y += 36
                        self.get_gem_position(x, y)

            else:
                print('Not Found')
                self.move_camera()
    def get_gem_position(self,x,y):
        screen_pos = x, y
        pyautogui.moveTo(screen_pos[0], screen_pos[1], 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
        self.mouse_click()

    def mouse_click(self):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.doubleClick()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.click_gather()

    def click_gather(self):
        screen = self.main_agent.screen1
        march_location = cv.matchTemplate(screen,
                                          self.gather,
                                          cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        march_loc_arr = np.array(march_location)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(march_loc_arr)
        threshold = 0.5
        if max_val >= threshold:
            x, y = max_loc
            x += 100
            y += 32
            screen_pos = x, y
            pyautogui.moveTo(screen_pos[0], screen_pos[1], 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.click_new_troop()
        else:
            print('Not Found')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.move_camera()

    def click_new_troop(self):
        screen = self.main_agent.screen1
        march_location = cv.matchTemplate(screen,
                                          self.troop,
                                          cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        march_loc_arr = np.array(march_location)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(march_loc_arr)
        threshold = 0.5
        if max_val >= threshold:
            print('Found2')
            x, y = max_loc
            x += 100
            y += 35
            screen_pos2 = x, y
            pyautogui.moveTo(screen_pos2[0], screen_pos2[1], 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.send_march()
        else:
            print('Not Found')
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            print('Go sleep 3min')
            time.sleep(180)



    def send_march(self):
        screen = self.main_agent.screen1
        march_location = cv.matchTemplate(screen,
                                          self.time,
                                          cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        march_loc_arr = np.array(march_location)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(march_loc_arr)

        threshold = 0.5
        if max_val >= threshold:
            x, y = max_loc
            screen_pos = x, y
            pyautogui.moveTo(screen_pos[0], screen_pos[1], 0.5, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.move_camera()

    def move_camera(self):
        direction = self.movement_sequence[self.current_movement_index]
        if direction in ['up', 'down']:
            move_delay = 0.6
        else:
            move_delay = 0.8
        pyautogui.keyDown(direction)
        time.sleep(move_delay)
        print('Moving to', direction)
        pyautogui.keyUp(direction)
        # Увеличиваем индекс для следующего движения, обеспечивая цикличность
        self.current_movement_index = (self.current_movement_index + 1) % len(self.movement_sequence)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.move_camera_count += 1
        print(self.move_camera_count)
        if self.move_camera_count == 400:
            self.move_camera_count = 0
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pyautogui.press('space')
            print('press scape1')
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.press('space')
            print('press scape2')
            time.sleep(3)
            self.start_place()
            self.current_movement_index = 0
        elif self.move_camera_count == 50:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.press('esc')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.press('esc')
        print('Moving to find_gem')


    def stop(self):
        print("stop...")
        #self.paused = True

    def start(self):
        print("start...")
        #self.paused = False

    def exit(self):
        if not self.q_pressed:
            print("Exiting...")
            #self.running = False
            #self.print_menu()
            #self.q_pressed = True

    def run(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey('e', self.stop)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('t', self.start)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('q', self.exit)
        self.start_place()
        while self.running:
            if not self.paused:
                self.find_gem()
            time.sleep(0.5)


I'm trying to find a way to send button and mouse clicks to an inactive window. but can't find a good library for this. For example, so that I could use and write something in the Google Dock on the second monitor while the lines and mouse clicks are being sent, the window on the main monitor.

Apparently pyautogui has trouble with multiple monitors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126468/pyautogui-in-specific-screen-app-in-2-monitors
